# How to implement C# SHA512 code snippet in Java?

Tags: java, c#

I struggle to implement the following C# code in Java to get SHA 512 value for given input.

C#

```cs
private static string GenerateHash (byte[] fileContent)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    byte[] hash;

    using (SHA512 shaM = SHA512.Create())
    {
        hash = shaM.ComputeHash(fileContent);
    }

    if(hash != null)
    {
        foreach (byte x in hash)
        {
            result += $"{x:x2}";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Java

```java
public class SHA512HashGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,  {
        String file = "HashString.txt";
        String fileContent = convertToString(file); 
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        messageDigest.update(fileContent.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : digest) {
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

Both programs give different SHA 512 value for same input.

I tried to input Base64 based string and executed Java program. The SHA 512 value which produced by Java Program is not matching with SHA 512 given by C#. (Only length is matched - 128 chars)

Could you please clarify what change is required in Java Program to achieve this?

Comment: Is `byte[] fileContent` and `fileContent.getBytes()` identical?

Comment: If you want the original bytes, why are you loading the file as a *string* to start with? I strongly suspect that the bytes you're hashing in the C# are not the same as the bytes you're hashing in the Java code. But without a [mcve], we really can't tell for sure.

Comment: You are calling String.format, and therefore *creating a new Formatter object,* for every single byte.  You don’t need a StringBuilder or a for-loop anymore;  just use [HexFormat.of().formatHex(b)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html).

Comment: Thank you Knittl and Jon Skeet. I could not see and issue in byte conversion in both the programs.

Comment: Hi VGR,  Thank you for reply.  I have come to know that HexFormat (java.util) is available from Java 17 onwards our version is Java 8. Could you please tell me is there any equivalent command in Java 8 to do this. Thank you.